# Calling ID by using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have page view details for assets, now i want to show graph as id they have, i make graph use node.js
how can i show my graph refer to id with using node.js ?
here my code for showing graph

```
static assetEmf(req, res, next) {
    const { startDate, endDate, groupBy } = req.body;
    sensor_emfs.findAll({
    }).then(result => {
        let emf = [];
        let humidity = [];
        let temperature = [];
        let series = [];
        if(result) {
            Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                var temp = {
                    x: moment(value.created_at).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
                    y: value.emf

                }
                emf.push(temp);
            })

            Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                var temp = {
                    x: moment(value.created_at).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
                    y: value.humidity

                }
                humidity.push(temp);
            })

            Object.entries(result).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                var temp = {
                    x: moment(value.created_at).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'),
                    y: value.temperature

                }
                temperature.push(temp);
            })

            series = [
                {name: 'EMF',data: emf},
                {name: 'Humidity',data: humidity},
                {name: 'Temperature',data: temperature}
            ];
        }
        res.status(200).send({name: 'EMF',data: emf})
    }).catch(error => {
        res.status(200).send(error)
    })
}
```

how can i call id by refered showing page view for assets at php ?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking. You want the id from the result? `result.id`?

Comment: i just want showing the graph refered by id at php page